# Django Unique Key on M2M Table

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a way to tell Django to create unique key based on a M2M relation?

I have the following table and I want the `host_id` and `hostname_id` pair to be unique.

**Table (app_host_names)**

- id
- host_id
- hostname_id

**models.py**

```
class Hostname(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)

class Host(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    names = models.ManyToManyField(Hostname)
```

Comment: You can define a through model that enforces this, otherwise you will have to override `ManyToManyField` or manage this yourself.